# How to Create Slidable Flexboxes like Google Play App Lists?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

`[Google Play slidable flexboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRlJR.jpg)` (Need at least 10 reputation to post images.)

It is a list of slidable flexboxes that is normally seen on Google Play store. It is list of flexboxes (apps) slidable to left from right manually! There are some sites(9apps) who already have created the same slidable flexboxes like Google Play store! So, it is now certain that it can be created by using HTML, JavaScript & CSS! I have tried to find out the codes to create the same slidable flexboxes in Google Search, but unfortunately they were not satisfying to me as they were not same.

So, how can I create the almost same slidable flexboxes like Google Play store app lists?

Comment: Just an idea you'd need some level of animation.  Not too familiar with Flexbox's but I'd put the flexbox in a container and have that said container move.  You could always inspect the element on the Google Play store and look at what they are doing in the Chrome Debug tools

Comment: Looking at the HTML it looks like that is a Carousel element, probably custom to Google but if you look at the CSS you'll see the transformations for the carousel a lot more to it than just that but should get you started.

Comment: https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2